# File transfer, browser to browser, local networks

Tags: file-upload, upload, download

How does browser to browser file transfer work. I can make a good guess on how [this](http://www.justbeamit.com/) site does it because the file is transferred through a third party server. I want to know how it would be possible to build something like [this](http://www.filesovermiles.com/) site. It claims the file doesn't touch a third party server (if none is needed, eg. file sharing over a home or office network) and the speeds achieved seem to corroborate this.